# Get bluetooth signal strength connected devices android

Tags: android

any body with piece of code of this implementation? 
i saw any implementation of function with BluetoothGatt but this implementation  no detect my device

my device is HC-05 arduino bluetooth

Comment: Are you asking about the RSSI on the Android side or on the Arduino bluetooth HC-05 module?

Comment: i am asking android side